# How to use brackets(options[,callbacks])

Tags: node.js

i'm new at here and im new at coding something at node.js. My question is how to use the brackets i mean, i'm working on a steam trade bot and i need to get understand how to use options and callbacks. Let me give you a example,

[image]

For example i'm writing something, i wanted to a take tradeoffer.

is that gonna be like that?

```
makeOffer.partnerAccountId: 'mysteamid';
makeOffer(accessToken[, itemsFromThem]
```

or something. Really i can't understanding. I didn't have ever been a pro at programing languages and i was worked little bit python. It was understable than this. Please help, if i can understand little, i can solve it. Thanks. Sorry for my bad Eng.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't have full code of what You've done.

But I'll give necessary part of it.

Look here:

```
var SteamTradeOffers = require('steam-tradeoffers');
var offers = new SteamTradeOffers();

// look at api, it needs 2 arguments
// 1. offer object, that consist of params like this:
var offer = { 
  partnerAccountId: 'steam id goes here',
  accessToken: 'access token goes here',
  itemsFromThem: [{
   appid: 440,
   contextid: 2,
   amount: 1,
   assetid: "1627590398"
  }],
  itemsFromMe: [{
   appid: 440,
   contextid: 2,
   amount: 1,
   assetid: "1627590399"
  }],
  message: "Hello! Checkout what I'm offering You ;)"
};
offers.makeOffer(offer, 
  function(err, result){ // 2. callback function that will handle result of makeOffer
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: You're missing the point; he's not understanding what the notation actually means.

Comment: @JesseTG normal developer, can understand from example. If You'll explain logic and etc. he will not get in idea.

Comment: Really i understand, thanks for example num8er, just i was need this. I can do something now, even if i can't, i can try to do. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

The brackets are documentation notation indicating that those parameters are optional, and can be omitted from any given invocation.

They are not indicative of syntax you should be using in your program.

Both of these styles should work, given that documentation. The callback being optional.

```
makeOffer({ ... });

makeOffer({ ... }, function (...) { ... });
```

*Dots indicate more code - in this case an object definition, function parameters, and the function body.*

Some other examples of this type of documentation notation:

MDN Array: [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: i really didn't understand, im gonna sleep, im working at on this for 14 hours. Thanks for try, good nights.

Answer (score 0):

<s>`makeOffer(accessToken[, itemsFromThem])` is not JavaScript syntax.  It's just common notation that's used to indicate that the function can take any number of arguments, like so:</s>

```
makeOffer(accessToken, something, somethingElse);
makeOffer(accessToken, something, secondThing, thirdThing);
makeOffer(accessToken);
```

Check the documentation for more details on how that library behaves.

Comment: look at documentation of module which he is trying to use: https://github.com/Alex7Kom/node-steam-tradeoffers#makeofferoptions-callback  there are only 2 arguments.

Comment: Crap, you're right.  Okay, I concede, I am being a bit of a schmuck.

Comment: it's ok. I know such guys, who are trying to learn development directly diving to business (tradebot for steam), so they need to quickly get it done. It does not matter what You'll try to teach. They learn on their mistakes (: